# Incrementing addresses

Tags: c

I have a variable word that points to a characters. However whenever I try to increment &c, I get a bizarre value for c:

```
char *word = "testing";
char c = *word; // 't'
c = *(&c + 1); // want to be 'e'
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Because c is not a pointer.

Comment: &c is a pointer, but it does not point to the same t as in word

Comment: `&c` is "address of variable c". so if `c` is stored at memory address 57, the new value of `c` will be 58. It won't be the address of the string 'testing'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line

```
char c = *word; // 't'
```

allocates space in memory on the stack for a new char (`c`). It then sets this char to be `'t'`, because that is what is at `*word`. The address of c (`&c`) is not going to be the same as `word`.

To do what you're trying to do:

```
char c;                 //allocate space for a char
char *word = "testing";
c = *word;              // c == 't'
c = *(word + 1);        // c == 'e'
```

Answer (score 2):

The address of `c` is somewhere on the stack. It's different from the address that `word` points to. You want to do this:

```
char *word = "testing";
char *c = word; //same as &word[0]
*c; //'t'
c += 1;
*c; //'e'
```

Answer (score 1):

`c` is a single `char` object whose value is `'t'`.

`&c + 1` is a valid address, pointing just after `c`'s location in memory, but there's no object there. (It's valid only because of a special-case rule that permits a pointer to point just past the end of an array, where a single object is treated as a 1-element array.) Dereferencing that address causes undefined behavior; in practice, it will probably fetch whatever garbage happens to be stored just after `c` in memory.

By initializing `c` to `*word`, you didn't make `c` point to the first character of the string, you made it contain a *copy* of the first character of the string.